# Keeping JMS session always active

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jms, spring-jms

We need know how to make Jms queue always active. and whenever the request received to JMS queue should pick the message.
if tomcat server is idle some time no request are received on jms queue for specific time or day, then next day or after some time any request landed to JMS queue its not picking that message in queue . we need to restart the tomcat server to pick the message and process it.
JMS Property

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate" id="remoteJndiTemplate">
<property name="environment">
    <props>
        <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://10.0.0.0:2222</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jnp.interfaces:org.jboss.naming</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

JMS Queue Receiving the Message:

```
<from id="_from2" uri="jms:queue:TestTocrmQueue"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most often caused by some network component silently dropping an idle connection.

Most brokers have some mechanism to keep idle connections alive with heartbeats etc. This is not part of the JMS spec so you will have to explore your vendor's documentation to find out how to configure it; it's usually referred to as heartbeats or keepalives.